# x-editable with Bootstrap 4 table and jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, x-editable

I'm trying to implement xeditable ([xeditable[1](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/tree/develop/dist/jquery-editable)) with a Bootstrap 4  table. I am trying to emulate this snippet (https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/edit-forms-inline-using-x-editable-editor-11973728) with no luck.  Here is what I have in my index.php file:

```
 <th data-field="macAddr_id" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input" data-editable="true">Mac Address</th>
```

........................

```
<?php
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  ?>
   <tr>
     <td> <a href="#" id="macAddr" data-type="text" data-pk="1" class="editable editable-click editable-empty" data-abc="true"><?php echo $row["macAddr_id"]; ?></a> </div>
   </tr>
```

The table is displayed fine.  In my index.js (which I include in my index.php file),I have:

```
$('#macAddr').editable({
    mode: 'inline',
    type: 'text',
    name: 'macAddr',
    pk: 1
});
```

But editing does not work.  When I single-click or double-click, I get nothing.

I have tried multiple versions of x-editable, including:

https://github.com/Talv/x-editable

https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html  (jquery version)

Neither works.  Is there something I am missing? Or a better plugin to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `a` tags is inside while loop so same id will get assign to each `a` tag . Instead change that to `class="macAddr"` . Then , use each loop to iterate and initialize editable plugin to each `a` tags with `class="macAddr"` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable()
  $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
  $.fn.editableform.buttons =
    '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>' +
    '</button>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm editable-cancel">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i>' +
    '</button>';
  //loop through each a tags
  $(".macAddr").each(function() {
    //intialize..
    $(this).editable({
      mode: 'inline',
      type: 'text',
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">ID</th>
      <th data-field="macAddr_id" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="input" data-editable="true">Mac Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <!--change to class-->
      <td> <a href="#" data-type="text" data-pk="1" class="editable editable-click editable-empty macAddr" data-abc="true">xyz</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td> <a href="#"  data-type="text" data-pk="1" class="editable editable-click editable-empty macAddr" data-abc="true">abc</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly - thanks!  One issue I ran into was using the bootstrap-edit and the bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js together.   Once I took the table-filter out and used your solution, everything work.s